# Syncdb not syncing few databases table in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Initially i started one project in Django installed cms , admin and few other apps.

Then i started new project , it was working fine . But now when i try to add same  apps like cms , backend admin then i get his error

```
Not synced (use migrations):
 - sentry
 - cms
 - menus
 - cms.plugins.text
 - cms.plugins.picture
 - cms.plugins.link
 - cms.plugins.file
 - cms.plugins.snippet
 - cms.plugins.googlemap
```

i want to know that why this happens. Can i install only one project in django

I am using different databases for those different projects and they have their own manage.py.

There may be the other reason for error but i just think that may be the reason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your project seems to use [South](http://south.aeracode.org) as a migration tool. You are required to 'migrate' the apps by typing:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: i have just installed south but i am not using it . but what is migration and why i need it

Comment: Your project uses South. Have a look at the installed_apps, you'll see a 'south' entry there. Please consult to South's website for further information.